# couldnt make this batch script function to write to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried many ways to make this batch script write to file without success

```
>>output.txt(
for /f "tokens=5 delims=ms " %a in ('tracert -4 -d -h 1 google.com ^|find " ms "') do @echo %a
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>output.txt(
```

must be

```
>>output.txt (
```

since `(` is a legitimate filename character.